# GCM vs Custom implementation for sending notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

I'm building a system which has following requirements:

1. Client device registers with Server & REGID is saved. Ex. 12 (ID) & the n system user can send a notification to the selected REGIDs or REGID depending upon requirement.
2. Possibility of attaching files or images (Optional)

I'm confused to go for GCM or build custom code for my requirements, the most apt thing I found was GCM Topic Messaging.
And the 2nd thing is totally optional.

I'd love to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use parse (parse.com) and create channel per user or ID user and send GCM messages, images, text, etc for x channels... on the format CLASS-ID_PEOPLE.

Comment: This seems nice, can you have any more suggestions?